# Projecting in DAX

Tags: projection, dax

I am still relatively new to the DAX language, but my question is how do I forward project based off of date specific variables such as holiday performance boosts or yearly low periods.

I have 2 tables. One that has sales data for multiple SKUs and the other has the time of year variables.

I have my forecasted values in a small table with the date ranges and % change needed like so.

```
date    increase
1/1/2018    1
4/14/2018   .9
5/1/2018    1
6/1/2018    .85
8/1/2018    1.05
11/18/2018  1.25
```

I have only gotten as far as projecting out 30 days into the future using the DATEADD function with a CALCULATETABLE.

```
transOrder30:=VAR Days = -30
Return
SUMX(
CALCULATETABLE(sales,
    DATEADD(
        'Calendar'[Date] ,Days,DAY),
            ALL(sales[date])
            ),
    sales[organicOrder])
```

where organic_orders:=SUM(sales[organicOrder])

So how do I take this projected 30 days and duplicate it throughout time then multiply it by the time of year change?

In Excel that would be as easy as organicOrder*vlookup(date,A:B,2).

I have looked through this guys post but it doesn't work for me.

https://blog.gbrueckl.at/2015/04/recursive-calculations-powerpivot-dax/

Any help is appreciated!

Example:

```
Date    Orders      Date    ToY
2/1/2018    15      2/10/2018   1
2/2/2018    19      2/20/2018   1.2
2/3/2018    12      3/2/2018    1.5
2/4/2018    18          
2/5/2018    15          
2/6/2018    14          
2/7/2018    11          
2/8/2018    16          
2/9/2018    16          
2/10/2018   18          
2/11/2018   15.40   Projection   =avg(orders)*ToY   
2/12/2018   15.40   Projection      
2/13/2018   15.40   Projection      
2/14/2018   15.40   Projection      
2/15/2018   15.40   Projection      
2/16/2018   15.40   Projection      
2/17/2018   15.40   Projection      
2/18/2018   15.40   Projection      
2/19/2018   15.40   Projection      
2/20/2018   18.48   Projection      
2/21/2018   18.48   Projection      
2/22/2018   18.48   Projection      
2/23/2018   18.48   Projection      
2/24/2018   18.48   Projection      
2/25/2018   18.48   Projection      
2/26/2018   18.48   Projection      
2/27/2018   18.48   Projection      
2/28/2018   18.48   Projection      
3/1/2018    18.48   Projection      
3/2/2018    23.10   Projection      
3/3/2018    23.10   Projection
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output you want?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I have attached a small example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new table where you will put your projections. One way to do this is New Table > `Projection = CALENDARAUTO()`.

Now that you have a date column, we'll add a projected orders calculated column.

(I will assume you have two table, `Sales` and `Forecast` where the former corresponds to `Date` and `Orders` columns of the first 10 rows of your example data and the latter corresponds to the `Date` and `ToY` data.)

```
ProjectedOrders = 
    VAR AverageOrder = AVERAGE(Sales[Orders])
    VAR ToYDate = CALCULATE(MAX(Forecast[Date]),
                      Forecast[Date] < EARLIER(Projection[Date]))
    RETURN
        IF(Projection[Date] < MIN(Sales[Date]),
            BLANK(),
            IF(Projection[Date] IN VALUES(Sales[Date]),
                LOOKUPVALUE(Sales[Orders], Sales[Date], Projection[Date]),
                AverageOrder * LOOKUPVALUE(Forecast[ToY], Forecast[Date], ToYDate)
            ))
```

This gives a blank if the date is before any of your sales data and duplicates the sales data for the dates where sales data exists. Otherwise, it multiplies the average order with the last `ToY` value that occurs before the date in that row.

Comment: Thank you for this. How would you adjust this if Sales[Orders] is a measure like SUM(orders) due to multiple sales lines per day.

Comment: You would use something like `CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Orders]), Sales[Date] = EARLIER(Projection[Date]))` instead of that first `LOOKUPVALUE` line.

Comment: Thank you again. One last question, for the AverageOrder Var how would that look if I wanted to change the date range I wanted to take the average from? AKA Last 30 days or 14 days.

Comment: You can wrap the `AVERAGE` function in a `CALCULATE` and add whatever filtering you need there.